# How can I install Windows Live Essential 2011 in Windows XP and Windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

How can I install Windows Live Essentials 2011 in Windows XP and Windows mobile 6.5
Is there any work around for this.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you cannot do that. Check the [requirements](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-2011-system-requirements).

Comment: I am aware of the specification. Is there any work around or hack.